# Change Different Deployment Targets for Different SDK's

Tags: swift, podfile

I need to add two deployment target values for two  different SDK's.

Is there any way that we can do it in Podfile.

I knew that we can add different swift versions or other setting but i didnt know how can add deployment targets.

It will be great if i could get help on this.

Comment: You can use **abstract_target** in your podfile. you can read more on [different_deployment_target_podfile](https://guides.cocoapods.org/using/the-podfile.html)

Comment: Thank you. But how we are going to set the deployment target there. If we have different targets we can set the value, same target we cant duplicate right.